# How can we encourage someone to do somethings

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

As our discussion at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/422585/271901), we got out a result that **Try what you can't** and **Do what you can't** is contradiction, then how can we encourage someone to try/do something that they can't/don't do in the pass?

#### Edit:

I meant encouraging somebody to try, maybe they failed in the past or the fails now, but something sometimes may success after a serval tries, not everything total fails when you failed once.

Comment: Why would you want to encourage someone to do something impossible? Could you please add more context?

Comment: @Cardinal I updated it at edit part

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you were running into on ELU is that you don't seem to understand that "can't" means "completely unable." I think the idea you are trying to get at may be something like this:

> If you can't do something now, practice it until you can.

Simply adding "now" in there opens up the possibility that it could change.

There's also a saying in English: "If at first you don't succeed, try, try, again."